# Problems sorting a 2-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, sorting, julia

I want to get the filename of the latest file in a directory. latest is based on creation time.

Currently I stuck in sorting the 2-dimensional array. I do not know how I should sort it? I get the following error

> ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Any,1})

The 2-dimensional array looks like this:

```
Any[
    Any[1.47913e9,"foo.csv"],
    Any[1.47913e9,"bar.csv"],
    Any[1.47913e9,"foobar.csv"]
]
```

#### newestfile.jl

```py
dfolder = "C:\\Users\\Foo\\Downloads"
cd( dfolder )
dfiles = readdir( "." )

files=[]

#println( dfiles )
for file in dfiles
    created = ctime( file )
    push!(files, [created, file]  )
end

println( files )

# sort the timestamp
sort!( files ) # This throws an error

# grab the newst file and display the filename
```

How do I display the newest file in the directory?

Comment: Note on terminology: that is an array of arrays rather than a 2-d arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
julia> sort!( files, by = e -> e[1])
```

The last item is the newest one:

```
julia> files[end]
2-element Array{Any,1}:
1.48061e9 ".whatever"
```

The filename is:

```
julia> files[end][2]
".whatever"
```